# SQL Server mail issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, email, send

I was wondering if anyone had this issue before. We have the emailer send emails out to our clients and inside this email, there is a link to their appropriate download. However, once it reaches SOME clients, the link seems to be missing a few characters (rendering the link useless).

I've check through the sysmail_mailitems but the body of the email I pull from there has the correct link. Just for some reason for some clients the characters are missing.

Has anyone had something weird like this happen? Also, the characters missing in the link are in the exact same spots.

Comment: It would be nice to see how you form the email body string.

Comment: are the missing characters in spots that follow '\' characters?

Comment: Might have something to do with the collation of your recipients' email clients?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Does "the emailer" mean Database Mail? How do you create the email content, including the link? Can you show some examples of the good and bad links?

Comment: but the strings are perfectly fine on our end..it's just when some clients get it..there are characters missing

they do not follow the '\' character

sql server 2008

a good link would be: http://www.test.com/test.aspx?sample=1FD91F17-759F-4B07-A778-B73D46995D11

a bad link would be: http://www.test.com/test.aspx?sample=1FD91F17-759F-4B07-A778-B746995D11

now that i notice...the characters '3D' are gone

Comment: If you're sure that the email is correct when it leaves your mail server (i.e. your SMTP server, not your SQL Server) then you'll have to investigate further with your clients to see if they have any issues on their side.